# Using the BackgroundWorker and Updating the UI

Tags: vb.net

```
Private _Proxies As New List(Of String)
Private _Array As New List(Of String)

Private Sub btnLeech_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Leech_btn.Click
    Worker.RunWorkerAsync(_Array)
End Sub

'Open a bunch of new threads to download sources of webpages
Private Sub Fetch(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                 ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Worker.DoWork
    Dim websiteUri As Uri = Nothing
    Dim Website As String
    For I = 0 To _Array.ToList.Count - 1
        Website = _Array(I)
        Using wc As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient
            AddHandler wc.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf SourceDownloaded
            If Uri.TryCreate(Website, UriKind.Absolute, websiteUri) Then
                wc.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri(Website))
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
            Else
                If Notify.Checked = True Then
                    TrayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1, "Invalid website", "There was a invalid site in the list." & Website.ToString, ToolTipIcon.Error)
                    Me.TrashSite_list.Items.Add(Website)
                Else
                    Me.TrashSite_list.Items.Add(Website)
                End If
            End If
        End Using
    Next
End Sub
'Grab the proxies from the webpages
Private Sub SourceDownloaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim strRegex As String = "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\:[0-9]{1,5}\b"
    Dim myRegexOptions As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.None
    Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions)
    Dim frm As New Proxies
    Dim i As Integer
    My.Settings.Proxies = New StringCollection
    If e.Error Is Nothing Then
        For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(e.Result)
            If myMatch.Success Then
                Try
                    i += i
                    _Proxies.Add(myMatch.ToString)
                    Worker.ReportProgress(i)
                Catch ex As WebException
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        ex.ToString,
                        ErrorToString,
                        Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                End Try
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles Worker.ProgressChanged
    Proxy_list.Items.AddRange(_Proxies.ToArray)
        Proxy2_lbl.Text = "Proxies: " & Proxy2_list.Items.Count
    Proxy_lbl.Text = "Proxies: " & Proxy2_list.Items.Count
End Sub
```

This is my code and I want it to update the UI with it but I am unsure how to do so. I am looking for an example with commenting so I can understand it. So far I have posted on a few sites and everyone will tell me what to do or give me an example but nobody will tell me what to do with the example! They expect me to know what the code does, but If I knew what it did, do you really think I'd be asking questions? Anyways, back on topic:

This is what I am trying to accomplish. When I click Leech_btn, it adds all my websites from Website_list into an Array called "Array". It then runs the backgroundworker with the array as the argument. The background worker downloads the string of a website from the list and moves it over to SourceDownloaded to be filtered. (It removes all the proxies from the website) It then should display the proxies in Proxy_list but this is where I am having trouble. What should I do?

Comment: Your fetch function receives an array of strings but when then cast the e.Argument as a String.
I'm pretty sure you also get an exception on Website = Array(I) when I = Array.Length

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, the problem is at

```
Dim Proxies() As String = My.Resources.SiteList6.Split(vbNewLine)
Proxy_list.Items.AddRange(Proxies)
```

It is because the UI and worker in different thread. you can add this:

```
Private Delegate Sub UpdateListDelegate(byval itemName() as string)
Private Sub UpdateList(byval itemName() as string)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New UpdateListDelegate(AddressOf UpdateList), itemName)
    Else
        ' UpdateList
        ' add list add code
        Proxy_list.Items.AddRange(itemName)
    End If
End Sub
```

In your code, replace "Proxy_list.Items.AddRange(Proxies)" with

```
 UpdateList(Proxies)
```

See [vb.net: listbox.items.add() throws exception in same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072621/vb-net-listbox-items-add-throws-exception-in-same-class/13074534#13074534) , a similar question.

Comment: Check my thread now, I have added a different method of going about it.